# Not able to pass data from one component to other component using service when the receiving component is not loaded yet

Tags: angular, service

I have a component named as admin and one other component named as edit. I want to send date from admin to this component and for this I have created Edit Service,but not able to fetch the data when the Edit component is loaded

admincomponent.ts:

```
public editUseCase(){
    console.log("Edit button");
    this.editService.setUseCaseDes(this.UseCaseDes);
    this.editService.EditUseCase.emit(this.UseCaseDes);
    this.router.navigate([
      `/admin/${this.AppName}/${this.UseCaseId}/edit-useCase`
   ]);
  }
```

EditService

```
export class EditService{
    usecasedis:any;
   
    EditUseCase =new EventEmitter<string>();

    setUseCaseDes(des:any){
       console.log("Inside Edit service"+des); 
       this.usecasedis=des;
    }

    getUseCaseDes(){
      return this.usecasedis;
    }
}
```

EditComponent.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.editService.EditUseCase.subscribe(
      (usecasedes:string)=>alert("usecasedes"+ usecasedes)
    );
  }
```

There is no error coming up, I am able to set the data by using setter but not able to fetch the data in Edit Component

Comment: can you be more explicit on the file contents ? like constructor parameters, is `@Injectable()` present on the service file, when do you fire an `EditUseCase` event (using `EditUseCase.emit(...)`) ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you injecting the service in both components? You can so this in the constructor of each component, and don't forget to decorate your service with the @Injectable() decorator.

Another aproach: If you have one component inside another, you can use @ViewChild

[Angular ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wired well the service in your angular module.
You should not use `EventEmitter` inside a service, it is a component thing. Instead, use RxJS BehaviorSubject:

```
@Injectable()
export class EditService{
    private usecasedis$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

    setUseCaseDes(des:any){
       console.log("Inside Edit service"+des); 
       this.usecasedis$.next(des);
    }

    getUseCaseDes(): Observable<any>{
      return this.usecasedis$.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Thing to know about a BehaviorSubject (and Subjects) is that you have to manually unsubscribe in your component:

EditComponent.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.EditUseCaseSubscribtion = this.editService.EditUseCase.subscribe(
      (usecasedes:string)=>alert("usecasedes"+ usecasedes)
    );
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.EditUseCaseSubscribtion.unsubscribe();
}
```

And so your admin component don't have to `emit`, the service does it alone:

In admincomponent.ts:

```
public editUseCase(){
    console.log("Edit button");
    this.editService.setUseCaseDes(this.UseCaseDes);
    // this.editService.EditUseCase.emit(this.UseCaseDes);
    this.router.navigate([
      `/admin/${this.AppName}/${this.UseCaseId}/edit-useCase`
   ]);
  }
```